# Error while replacing fragments in navbar in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm working with navbar in android studio. I'm trying to replace fragments through getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace() but it is not working and continuously giving me error. Here is the code:

```
public class UserNavbar extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

private DrawerLayout mydrawerlayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle atoggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_navbar);

    mydrawerlayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    atoggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mydrawerlayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);  //Done
    mydrawerlayout.addDrawerListener(atoggle);
    atoggle.syncState();  
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
  switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.home:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new User_Home_Fragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.personalinformation:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new Personal_Info_Frag()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.settings:

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new Settings_Frag()).commit();
            break;
}
mydrawerlayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}}
```

Here is the error:
[image: Error Message]

The User_Home_Fragment(), Personal_Info_Frag() & Settings_Frag() are developed. I will post them too if needed.

I'll be thankful if someone has any suggestions. Regards

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the new keyword becase **replace** method have two arguments first one is container id and second one is fragment instance.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new User_Home_Fragment()).commit();
```

Comment: I've tried it but it's still giving me error
error:incompatible types:User_Home_Fragment cannot be converted into Fragment
and same for the other two

Comment: Which fragment did you import ?
`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` ?
or
`import android.app.Fragment` ?

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment